# Windows Phone 8 - List Picker two level selection

Tags: windows-phone-8, listpicker, multi-level, itemselector

I am building a Video Application where each video has many resolutions

The video list is bound to ListPicker, but when the user selects a video I have to make him select the resolution options. (240, 360, 480)

Example:

Consider we have: Celebrity Video, National Video, Sport Video. They are listed like:

[image: Videos ListPicker before expanding]

[image: Videos ListPicker after expanding]

Now when the user selects a video I have to make him choose on which resolution he wants to play the video. Like a ListPicker inside the main ListPicker

I don't know how to approach that.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you have only one list picker in the screen,you can use another list picker below your first list picker and use the selected event of the first list picker to bind the visibility to the second list picker( which contains the resolutions.)

on page loads it only contains first list picker and once the item is selected in the first list picker, the second list picker kicks in( visibility is made to visible ) where the user is allowed to select the resolutions. hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your response.
but the problem is that I have a long list of videos and I'm displaying them on the FullMode of ListPicker.
It's like a full page ListPicker filled with items. there will be no room left for another ListPicker to make the second selection.